# Adding individual UIImageViews for each item in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsarray

I am trying to add a individual UiImageView for each item in an array this is what I have so far

```
_shapeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cloud.png",@"star.png", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [_shapeArray count]; i++){
        // I make a UIImage, which I will draw later
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_shapeArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

        UIImageView* blockView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        blockView.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%320, arc4random()%460, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        [self.view addSubview:blockView];

    }
```

But as you can tell it just adds the last image in the array. I can not figure out a way to maybe add the array object number to the name of the UIImageView. Maybe I am going at it the wrong way, if so what would be the best way?

Comment: What result are you getting? Two image views, each with star.png as the image?

Comment: No only one UIImageView with the star image.

Comment: Probably cloud.png is not in your bundle. Try to delete the image, re-import it, select "Copy Item.." and flag your target in "Add to targets".

Comment: Ok thanks that weird becuase I tried it on a different iPad and it worked just fine. I had been stuck on that for a while. Ok next questions how can I add touch events to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but you need to make sure of a couple of things:
- That the file name actually exists in your bundle (check for uppercase/lowercase), you would not get an error message if it didn't, but it would not show the picture
- That the image sizes are not too large and don't cover each other

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the images in the same frame.

```
   blockView.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%320+SomeXValue, arc4random()%460+SomeYvalue, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```